# How do I iterate through an array object in javascript which works in Chrome, Firefox, but is structured differently in IE

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

So, I have a google map that I was using while developing in Chrome. The functionality works great, but when I tested in IE, (not my browser of choice), I am getting a gray space where the map should be, so i tore my whole View (MVC) apart and started to find where the problem was.

Look at the locations array, the map does appear when I load the array with the hardcoded values (i.e Chicago, Los Angeles, etc. ), but It does not appear and I get stack trace errors when I load it with the "array (comm) " that comes from my controller.

When I get to the line "for (item in comm[i]" ... item is null in IE, but not in Chrome, is there another way to decipher this?

Here is my code:

// Map options
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -100.4179324),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    var comm = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.regPoints));
    var cert = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.certPoints));
    var locations = [];
    var certLocs = [];
    var allMarkers = [];
    locations.push({ name: "Chicago", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878114, -87.629798), state: "Illinois" });
    locations.push({ name: "New York", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941), state: "New York" });
    locations.push({ name: "Los Angles", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243685), state: "California" });
    locations.push({ name: "Washington DC", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(38.907192, -77.036871), state: "District of Colombia" });
    locations.push({ name: "Cincinnati", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(39.103118, -84.512020), state: "Ohio" });
    locations.push({ name: "Houston", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(29.760427, -95.369803), state: "Texas" });
    locations.push({ name: "Seattle", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(47.606209, -122.332071), state: "Washington" });
    locations.push({ name: "Miami", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(25.761680, -80.191790), state: "Florida" });
    locations.push({ name: "Newark", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(40.735657, -74.172367), state: "New Jersey" });
    locations.push({ name: "Denver", latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(37.739236, -104.990251), state: "Colorado" });
    // Communities could be null if the Google maps is over the limit
    if (comm != null){
        for (i = 0; i < comm.length; i++) {
            var count = 0;
            var name = "";
            var lat = "";
            var long = "";
            var state = "";
            for (item in comm[i]) {
                count++;

                if (count == 2)
                    name = comm[i][item];
                if (count == 3)
                    lat = comm[i][item];
                if (count == 4)
                    long = comm[i][item];
                if (count == 5)
                    state = comm[i][item];

            }
            mylat = parseInt(lat, 10);
            mylong = parseInt(long, 10);
            locations.push({ name: name, latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(mylat, mylong), state: state });
        }
    }

    // Add the Markers to the map
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: locations[i].latlng, map: map, title: locations[i].name,
            html: "<h1>" + locations[i].state + "</h1>"
        });

        bounds.extend(locations[i].latlng);



    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
</script>
```

}

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get object properties. Why not simply expand them like `var long = comm[i].long;` etc?

Comment: it is weird thought that it is working in google, but I agree with you

Comment: this all worked!! thank you so much